# Removing rows of dataframe based on frequency of a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe (in R) that contains observations of animals in the wild (recording time/date, location, and species identification). I want to remove rows that contain a certain species if there are less than x observations of them in the whole dataframe. As of now, I managed to get it to work with the following code, but I know there must be a more elegant and efficient way to do it.

```
namelist <- names(table(ind.data$Species))
for (i in 1:length(namelist)) {
  if (table(ind.data$Species)[namelist[i]] <= 2) {
    while (namelist[i] %in% ind.data$Species) {
      j <- match(namelist[i], ind.data$Species)
      ind.data <- ind.data[-j,]
    }
  }
}
```

The `namelist` vector contains all the species names in the data frame `ind.data`, and the `if` statement checks to see if the frequency of the `i`th name on the list is less than x (`2` in this example).

I'm fully aware that this is not a very clean way to do it, I just threw it together at the end of the day yesterday to see if it would work. Now I'm looking for a better way to do it, or at least for how I could refine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ind.data)[, .SD[.N >2], Species]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! It's also quite speedy on large datasets, especially compared to my hacky `for` loop from before.

Comment: @twieg  Yes, data.table is very fast

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
library(dplyr)

new.ind.data <- ind.data %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(n() > 2) %>%
  ungroup()
```

An alternative using built-in functions is to use `ave()`:

```
group_sizes <- ave(ind.data$Species, ind.data$Species, FUN = length)
new.ind.data <- ind.data[group_sizes > 2, ]
```

Comment: I tried the second approach (using `ave()`) but it removed some groups that had more than 2. It removed groups with 12, 1, 2, 17, 2, 2, and 110 observations, respectively. Any ideas why?
I started with 20 species groups, but I ended up with 13 when I should have ended with 16.

Comment: that's numeric vs. character types. use `as.numeric(group_sizes) > 2`